# If statement within a for loop within a for loop - condition isn't being met

Tags: javascript

```
var text = [["1","1.","The Wagner diatribe and 'The Twilight of the Idols' were published"],["2","2.","suspect that the delay was due to the influence of the philosopher's"],["3","3.","bounds were marked by crosses. One notes, in her biography of him--a"]];

var amountOfTexts = text.length;
var tempArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<amountOfTexts; i++){
    tempArray = [];
    var current = text[i][2];
    var x = current.length;
    for(var j=0; j<x; j++){
        var y = j+1;
        if(current.substr(j,y) === " "){
            tempArray.push("counter");
        }
    }
console.log(tempArray.length);
    var nearlyWords = tempArray.length;
    var words = 1+nearlyWords;
    text[i].push(words);
}
```

This prints to console:

```
0
0
1
```

Where I'd be expecting:

```
11
12
12
```

It's meant to push the word count of the string in text[i][2] to text[i][3].
I have checked through it, and the closest thing to the problem is the conditions of the if statement... but they seem fine.
Question: why is it that it won't work?

Comment: Run a `console.log(current.substr(j,y))` before your condition, I bet you're not seeing any spaces :)

Comment: I get 3 zeroes printed with your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `substr` method wrong, it doesn't take the same parameters as the `substring` method.

Either use `substr` and specify the length as the second parameter:

```
if (current.substr(j, 1) === " ") {
```

or use `substring` with your current parameters:

```
if (current.substring(j, y) === " ") {
```

You can also use the `charAt` method to get a character, which seems more natural:

```
if (current.charAt(j) === " ") {
```

In newer browsers (IE 8 and later) you can also get characters using bracket syntax:

```
if (current[j] === " ") {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use current.charAt(j) === " " it would be more appropriate, here is code

```
for(var i=0; i<amountOfTexts; i++){
    ...

    for(var j=0; j<x; j++){
        var y = j+1;
        if(current.charAt(j) === " "){
            tempArray.push("counter");
        }
    }

   ...
}
```